# Regular Expression to get the last word from TitleCase, camelCase

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm trying to split a TitleCase (or camelCase) string into precisely two parts using javascript. I know I can split it into multiple parts by using the lookahead:

```
"StringToSplit".split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
```

And it will make an array `['String', 'To', 'Split']`

But what I need is to break it into precisely TWO parts, to produce an array like this:

```
['StringTo', 'Split']
```

Where the second element is always the last word in the TitleCase, and the first element is everything else that precedes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
"StringToSplit".split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z]+$)/); // ["StringTo", "Split"]
```

Improved based on lolol answer :

```
"StringToSplit".split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z]+$)/); // ["StringTo", "Split"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
s = "StringToSplit";
last  = s.replace(/^.*?([A-Z][a-z]+)(?=$)/, '$1'); // Split
first = s.replace(last, ''); // StringTo

tok = [first, last]; // ["StringTo", "Split"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
(function(){
  return [this.slice(0,this.length-1).join(''), this[this.length-1]];
}).call("StringToSplit".split(/(?=[A-Z])/));
//=> ["StringTo", "Split"]
```

In [other] words:

- create the `Array` using `split` from a `String`
- join a `slice` of that `Array` *without* the last element of that
  `Array`
- add that and the last element to a final `Array`